# PHP RSS feed help gettiong XML tags to apprear

Tags: php, rss, feed

I'm using the following code to generate an RSS feed for my site. When I run the code, I get an error: `Error on line 1 at column 14: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document`. If I take out the header(), the page runs, but the data is not formatted correctly, including the whole data array. When I ask for an RSS feed from my Word-Press site, I get the properly formatted XML response. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Thanks,

Darrell

**Code:**

```js
if($result){
       //header( "Content-type: text/xml");
        echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <rss version='2.0'>
       <channel>
       <title>Mom Minder | RSS</title>
       <link>www.darrellh89.com</link>
       <description>Mom Minder Notes</description>
       <language>en-us</language>";

   
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        //print_r($row);
        $rssTitle=$row["Title"];
        $rssNote=$row["Note"];
        $rssDate=$row["postDate"];
        $rssTime=$row["postTime"]; 
      
       echo "<item>
        <title>$rssTitle</title>
        <note>$rssNote</note>
       <postdate>$rssDate</postdate>
       <posttime>$rssTime</posttime>
       </item>";
   }
   echo "</channel></rss>";

    }
```

**Bad Response: The source code looks correct with ...**

`www.darrellh89.com Mom Minder Notes en-us Did you brush your teeth? 2020-12-21 08:30:00 What restaurant do you want to eat at? 2020-12-21 04:56:05 I'll pick you up at 5 2020-12-21 04:56:05 I'll pick you up at 4PM on Wednesday for the foot doctor 2020-12-22 04:56:05 Did you eat all your eggs? 2021-01-03 12:06:00`

**What I want**

```html
<channel>
    <title>Adventure Scuba</title>
    <atom:link href="https://ohioadventurescuba.com/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>https://ohioadventurescuba.com</link>
    <description>Individual Instruction on Your Schedule</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Sun, 20 Dec 2020 15:37:02 +0000</lastBuildDate>
```

Comment: I changed the echo statement to one building a string, then at the end of the string build used "echo htmlspecialchars($str);" This got me the xml tags I wanted. The file still doesn't work properly with a DOMDocument. The file also doesn't display in the same format as desired.